# Need an explanation of this paragraph "Measure Theory"

Tags: measure-theory

I will just quote a part of one proof in "On uniformly regular topological measure spaces by Babiker: page 781" vol43 No4 Duke Math. J. 1976.

> Let $I$ be the unit interval endowed with Lebesgue measure $m$. If $\mu$ is nonatomic probability (Radon) measure on (compact) space $X$, then there is $E\subset X$, $D\subset I$ with $\mu(E)=m(D)=0$ and a map $\psi\colon X\rightarrow I$ such that $\psi$ is a homeomorphism from $X\setminus E$ onto $I\setminus D$ and $m=\psi(\mu)$.

The author refer to this reference: N. Bourbaki, Elements De Mathematique Integration I, chaps 1-5, Paris, 1965: in chapter V page 85.

I do not know French to look at it. Could someone give me some steps proving the above result.

Comment: There exists an [English translation](http://books.google.com/books?id=4UVk-CCwnQ0C&pg=SL22-PA71), so if you have access to it, you might try to look there. (I guess it won't be easy to find the exact spot only using Google Books.)

Comment: I tried to get the translated book but I could not. I thought there might be something close to it or might be familiar to somebody here.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I think this statement is only for *metrizable* spaces. I could only find the exercise in French (part c) of [this exercise](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8JrIS.png) (Exercise 8 to Chapter V, §6, page 120 of my French edition)). Its translation should have the same number in [the English translation](http://books.google.com/books?id=4UVk-CCwnQ0C&pg=SL22-PA100) (the exercises appear to be direct translation of my French edition) and you should be able to find it on the next ten pages. I don't currently have access to these pages to check myself.

Comment: Come on, please someone share the solution of this exercise. I do not have access to the book.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Please write in the bounty description that the question has not been answered and still open for reward.

Comment: @DayanaChesslo AFAIK the description can be added only at the moment when the bounty is started.

Comment: The question on [mathoverflow.se]: [Need an explanation of this paragraph “Lebesgue Homoeomorphism”](https://mathoverflow.net/q/131244).

Answer (score 2):

This is what I found in my Russian edition of this book.

**Lemma 1.** Let $\mu$ be positive Borel measure on locally compact topological space $X$ and $A\subset X$ be $\mu$-measurable set with $\mu(A)>0$. Assume for all $\mu$-measurable $B\subset A$ either $\mu(B)=0$ or $\mu(B)=A$, then there exist $a\in A$ such that $\mu(A)=\mu(\{a\})$.

**Idea.** Consider intersection $P$ of all compact sets $K\subset A$ so that $\mu(K)=\mu(A)$. It will be the desired set.

**Lemma 2.** Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be two positive Borel measures on $\mathbb{R}$. Assume that $\mu([a,b))=\nu([a,b))$ for all $a<b$. Then $\mu=\nu$.

**Lemma 3.** Let $X$ be compact topological space and $\mu$ be positive non-atomic probability measure on $X$. Then there continuous map $\pi:X\to I$ to the unit interval $I$. Such that image of $\mu$ under $\pi$ is Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $I$.

**Sketch.** Following idea of the proof of the Uryson's lemma we construct a family of open sets $U(t)$ where $t\in I$ such that $U(0)=\varnothing$, $U(1)=X$, $\overline{U(t)}\subset U(t')$ for $t'<t$ and finally $\mu(U(t))=t$ for all $t\in I$. Using lemma 1 we can show that conditions $V$, $W$ two open $\mu$-measurable with $\overline{V}\subset W$ and $\mu(V)<\mu(W)$ implies existence of $\mu$-meausrable open set $U$ such that $\overline{V}\subset U\subset\overline{U}\subset W$ such that $1/3\mu(W\setminus V)\leq\mu(U\setminus V)\leq 2/3\mu(W\setminus V)$. Now we apply lemma 2.

**Theorem 1.** Assume all assumptions of previous lemma are satisfied plus $X$ is metrizable, then there exist $\mu$-measurable set $N\subset X$ of measure $0$ and $\lambda$-measurable subset $M\subset I$ of measure zero such that we have a homeomorphism $\pi:I\setminus M \to X\setminus N$ with the following property once $\pi$ is continuously (in fact arbitrarily) extended up to $\varphi:I\to X$ and $\pi^{-1}$ similarly extended to $\psi:X\to I$, then $\varphi\circ\lambda=\mu$ and $\psi\circ\mu=\lambda$

**Sketch.** For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we can find finite partition of $X$ consisting of set of $\mu$-measure $0$ and open $\mu$-measurable sets of diameter $\leq1/n$ and measure $\leq 1/n$. (Don't ask why $-$ this is a long story) Then using induction and taking the limit we get existence of continuous map $f:I\setminus S\to X$ (where $S$ is countable) such that $f\circ\lambda=\mu$. Moreover $f$ can be chosen to be homeomorphism from $I\setminus S$ onto the subset of $X$ of full measure.

Comment: In Lemma 1:something is missing "either $\mu(B)=$ or $\mu(B)=A$", either $\mu(B)=????$, it must be zero. This gives me some ideas but still vague !?? Could you please explain this further. With dozen of thanks

Comment: Dayana, honestly I just rewrote all of this from the book. It will took from me too much time to understand and write it here. It do not lust for bounty or upvotes, just answered for request to write what was written in the book. You may ask Martin to add into bounty description that existing answerrs do not contain enough details.

Comment: I thank you indeed for the context (in the book). I will ask Martin to that.

Comment: Good luck! I hope someone more competent will help you

Comment: I suppose that your translation comes mainly from [p.341](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xrqQM.png) and [p.342](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nOxeC.png) of this book. (Unless it is a different edition.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes, you are right.